# replacing 'N' with 'A', 'C', 'G', or 'T' from ABI file (sanger)

Tags: python, parsing, bioinformatics

My main issue is to manage to replace the unassigned nucleotides 'N' by the base which have the highest peak in the chromatogram.i'm trying to parse a ABI file in a ''pythonic'' way so i installed the abifpy module:

```
from abifpy import Trace
chrom=Trace("10F8_POL3.ab1")
chrom.data['tracepeaks']
```

Doing this gives me all the highest peak per position,BUT i don't know which base (A,C,G or T) matches with each peak. can anybody help me?

Comment: can you post the output of the `chrom.data['tracepeaks']`

Comment: you could also ask http://www.biostars.org/

Comment: the chrome.data['tracepeaks'] output: ***>>> chrom.data['tracepeaks']
(2, 12, 20, 30, 35, 52, 70, 82, 92, 99, 114, 138, 145, 152, 174, 188, 205, 218, 227, 239, 252, 264, 279, 289, 300, 311, 321, 331, 344, 352, 361, 373, 385, 395, 408, 419, 431, 441,....)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used the python library you mentioned  but I once had to write my own abi parser in java.  You have to get the raw channel data from the abi file.  There 4 channels: one for A, C, G and T.

**CAVEAT** - I'm not sure what your library will map these ABI key tags to so you'll have to look at the library's documentation.  I also haven't done anything sanger related in a long time, so I might be a little rusty.

I believe the channels can be in arbitrary order so you will have to get the order first from the  "FILTER WHEEL ORDER" tag which is named "FWO_".

Once you have the channel order, you then have to get the channel data which lists the positions of each channel.  I think the tag for that is called "DATA".  This will return many arrays.  I think ABI has lots of extra channels for other stuff that no one but a sequencing machine or operator cares about.  I think the channels you care about or the 9-12th.

So for example if the channel data for A was first from the FWO_ tag, then it will be in the 9th channel (or offset 8) f you get back an array of arrays.

Once you have the A, C, G and T channel data (their positions at each timepoint) you can see which one has the highest at the value at the peak offsets.

Hope that helps.

good luck

**UPDATE**

Looking at the python code it looks like FWO maps to "baseorder" and the channel data is "raw1", "raw2", "raw3", and "raw4", would be my guess.

**UPDATE 2 to address answers to comments**

1. how come the "raw1" (and the others) array is longer than the sequence?
   The values in the raw channel data is the position at each time point measured.  if you were to plot those values as the y value and the offset in the array as the x value you would see the waveforms with peaks and valleys.
   The peaks array is only the x positions into the raw data that the basecaller decided is a peak.  Usually a 1000bp sanger read will have 1000 peak values and about 15,000 raw positions.
2. am I the only who ever tried to "fix" sequences from Sanger sequencing os is it a common thing.
   It is a common thing to re-basecall sanger data.  In general it's more complicated than just taking the highest peak position.  There are quality issues and incorrect peaks due to dyeblobs and shouldering and mixed samples.

There are several basecallers including phred, kb basecaller which I think is from ABI.  There is also Celera's tracetuner which I think is the best one. However, I think it's difficult to build.  I looked around for the sourcecode and I think it's http://tracetuner.cvs.sourceforge.net/tracetuner/ but good luck getting it up and running.

I guess my point is, this is a solved problem so aside from trying to learn how the format works and fixing toy problems, it's better left to people who do signal processing.

3. 1/why the channel data is an array with negative values? 2/why the 'tracepeaks' array length (containning the highest peaks) matches the sequence length but the channel data doesn't?

   There should only be positive values in the position data. It should be unsigned 2bytes per position so a max value of 65536 My guess is the library you are using is returning them as signed values.  I answered the other part in #1 above.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, thanks to you my understanding of the library got better! i did retrieve the 4 channels and their order. The thing is: if a channel data gives all the peaks (from the chromatogram) per position, how come the "raw1" (and the others) array is longer than the sequence?  I mean the sequence length should match the number of peak per position for each base, shouldn't it?

Comment: Moreover, this question might be a little out of the topic but i have to ask: am i the only who ever tried to "fix" sequences from Sanger sequencing os is it a common thing? I mean: replacing the 'N' (unassigned bases) by looking at the highest peak on the chromatogram is something right or it shouldn't be done because if the base could not have been identified =>it means that the base calls fail and the chromatogram could be wrong? (I'm new in sequencing)

Comment: Have you an idea about: 1/why the channel data is an array with ***negative values***? 2/why the 'tracepeaks' array length (containning the highest peaks) matches the sequence length but the channel data doesn't?

Comment: Updated answer to answer your other questions